# Order two generic collections of complex type using a property

Tags: c#, generics

I have below method to compare two collections of any given complex type. Before perform the Sequence Equal operation , I need to sort both collections using a given property of the type being compared to make sure that objects are in the same order.

```
    public static bool CompareCollections<T>(IEnumerable<T> expectedCollection, IEnumerable<T> actualCollection,Func<T,string> selector)
    {
        if (expectedCollection.Count() != actualCollection.Count())
        {
            return false;
        }
        expectedCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
        actualCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
        return expectedCollection.SequenceEqual(actualCollection, new TypeComparer<T>());
    }
```

I am invoking the method as below

```
CompareCollections(first,second,x => x.ID)
```

Where first and second collections look like below, **NOTE** that both collections have the same two objects, but second one have its items in reverse order and I am expecting OrderBy method to sort it before compare for equality. But it doesn't sort as I expected

```
      var first = new List<Fee>()
      {
        new Fee
        {
            ID = "00001",
            BaseFee = "3.50"
        },
        new Fee
        {
            ID = "00002",
            BaseFee = "5.50"
        }
      };

      var second = new List<Fee>()
      {
        new Fee
        {
            ID = "00002",
            BaseFee = "5.50"
        },
        new Fee
        {
            ID = "00001",
            BaseFee = "3.50"
        }
      };
```

Comment: You need to assign the return of `expectedCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList()` into a variable.  `OrderBy` returns a new, ordered enumerable, it does not order the incoming collection in-place.

Comment: Oh.. yes, Thanks a ton for pointing out. I overlooked that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the results of `OrderBy().ToList()` into a new local variable.  [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb534966%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) returns an ordered sequence, it does not sort the incoming sequence in-place.  Thus:

```
var sortedExpectedCollection = expectedCollection.OrderBy(selector);
var sortedActualCollection = actualCollection.OrderBy(selector);

return sortedExpectedCollection.SequenceEqual(sortedActualCollection , new TypeComparer<T>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do that as following:

```
public static bool CompareCollections<T>(IEnumerable<T> expectedCollection, IEnumerable<T> actualCollection,
                                         Func<T, string> selector)
{
    var expectedAsList = expectedCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
    var actualAsList = actualCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList();

    return expectedAsList.Count == actualAsList.Count &&
           !expectedAsList.Where((t, i) => !t.Equals(actualAsList[i])).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expectedCollection = expectedCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
actualCollection = actualCollection.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
```

If sorting is the issue just assign the values to the list and do the comparison.